# Make an element use remaining height and scroll if necessary using bootstrap 4.1.3

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying make a div, #div6 in the snipp, with a unknown number of card divs inside. This div should use all remaining height and scroll if necessary. This div is part of the whole page layout and the page should use just the window space.

I'm trying this with the code below. It work perfectly in chrome. But it don't work in Firefox and Edge, not showing the scrollbar. I want use preferably just bootstrap 4.1.3 classes and minimum extra css. Any help to make this work in Firefox and Edge?

You need to run the snip in full page and try it with chrome anwith Firefox/Edge to see the differences.

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .overflow-auto {
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .card-main {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="card card-main">
        <h5 class="card-header text-center bg-primary text-white">Agenda</h5>
        <div class="card-body h-100 d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="form-group row bg-success flex-shrink-0" id="div1">Some content here</div>
            <div class="form-group row mt-1 d-flex flex-fill flex-grow-1">
                `<div class="col-auto bg-danger d-flex flex-column" id="div2">
                    <table class="bg-secondary" style="border: solid grey 1px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>r1c1</td>
                            <td>r1c2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>r2c1</td>
                            <td>r2c2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="form-group row flex-shrink-0">
                        <div class="col-6" id="div3">Date text</div>
                        <div class="col-3" id="div4">Today</div>
                        <div class="col-3" id="div5">Other icon</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row d-flex flex-fill flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
                        <div class="col-12 overflow-auto" id="div6">
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card0 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card1 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card2 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card3 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card4 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card5 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card6 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card7 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card8 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card9 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card10 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card11 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card12 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card13 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card14 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card15 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card16 content</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you share image of difference

Answer (score 0):

> not showing the scrollbar in Firefox and Edge

For that you need to change overflow-y property

from

> overflow-y: hidden;

to

> overflow-y: scroll;

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .overflow-auto {
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .card-main {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="card card-main">
        <h5 class="card-header text-center bg-primary text-white">Agenda</h5>
        <div class="card-body h-100 d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="form-group row bg-success flex-shrink-0" id="div1">Some content here</div>
            <div class="form-group row mt-1 d-flex flex-fill flex-grow-1">
                `<div class="col-auto bg-danger d-flex flex-column" id="div2">
                    <table class="bg-secondary" style="border: solid grey 1px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>r1c1</td>
                            <td>r1c2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>r2c1</td>
                            <td>r2c2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="form-group row flex-shrink-0">
                        <div class="col-6" id="div3">Date text</div>
                        <div class="col-3" id="div4">Today</div>
                        <div class="col-3" id="div5">Other icon</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row d-flex flex-fill flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
                        <div class="col-12 overflow-auto" id="divAgendaDia">
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card1 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card2 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card3 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card4 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card5 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card6 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card7 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card8 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card9 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card10 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card11 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card12 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card13 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card14 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card15 content</div></div>
                            <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card16 content</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did not meet my needs. I updated the issue to make it clearer. I would appreciate your review. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `overflow-y: hidden`, try using `overflow-y: scroll`.

Comment: Did not meet my needs. I updated the issue to make it clearer. I would appreciate your review. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to the problem. This is a known firefox bug. Just add "style =" max-height: 0; "" into the child div and the scrollbar is perfectly displayed. Necessary also remove the overflow class in the #div6.

Below the full adjusted code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example nested</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .overflow-auto {
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .card-main {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="card card-main h-100">
      <h5 class="card-header text-center bg-primary text-white">Agenda</h5>
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <div class="form-group row bg-success flex-shrink-0" id="div1">Some content here</div>
        <div class="form-group row d-flex flex-fill flex-grow-1">
          <div class="col-auto bg-danger d-flex flex-column" id="div2">
            <table class="bg-secondary" style="border: solid grey 1px;">
              <tr><td>row1col1</td><td>row1col2</td></tr>
              <tr><td>row2col1</td><td>row2col2</td></tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="form-group row flex-shrink-0">
              <div class="col-6" id="div3">Date text</div>
              <div class="col-3" id="div4">Today</div>
              <div class="col-3" id="div5">Other icon</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-fill overflow-auto">
              <div class="col-12" id="div6" style="max-height: 0;">
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card0 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card1 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card2 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card3 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card4 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card5 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card6 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card7 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card8 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card9 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card10 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card11 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card12 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card13 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card14 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card15 content</div></div>
                <div class="card"><div class="card-body">Card16 content</div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```